# How can I leave some kind of a mark in two-dimensional array that will tell the program to do something in this location

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, jframe

I am working on a little game that uses two-dimensional array for a board we play on. I implemented `Undo` method that will go back in history step by step with every Button click. The thing is in some cases the `Undo` method must do something else in a special situation and it might happen many times during the game.

I know the one way would be to store 'x' and 'y' (which are responsible for position on the board) when I reach the place where it will be needed to do something else if we come back here later. Then add `if` in `Undo Action Listener` that if position we come back to `.equals` any of stored `x` and `y` then do the thing. But it is quite not efficient I would say and I am wondering if there is a way to leave a mark that will tell the program that when I come back here the `Boolean` I created will `.equal` true and do the thing.

Here is the overview of the board:
[image: Overview of the board]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why an `if` statement will be inefficient. I will add constant time (if only your `equals` method has constant time) to your `undo` operation, so the big-o time of your operation will not be modified.

However, if you prefer another way to do that, then you could save an object in each cell. That `object` should have a boolean property that you will check when doing the `undo` operation.

I would prefer using an if statement, but is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 2-dimensional array - an array of what? Considering you have letters in your picture I presume something like String[][].

However you can also do an array of your own class. Something like a class "Cell".
Give this class two members - firstly the payload (aka the data you currently have) and secondly a boolean as your mark.

Comment: I meant array of ints. Because board is made of ints. I will take a look into those Cells. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Separate concerns. The board shouldn’t have to also store its history. Keep a journal of actions and have a way to play them back in reverse.

This is exactly how relational databases cater for rollbacks; they keep a log of every change and can undo everything in it. The log is usually a before snapshot of the state of the data being changed. One simple way you could implement it in your case would be to store a snapshot of every board and undo would simply swap historic boards in for the current board.

This might seem “heavy”, but it’s the way massive high transaction rate databases do it, and it’s way simpler to implement and bulletproof, because you don’t need to know how to undo a specific action. Further, it means boards need to know less, in fact they don’t even need to know they can be undone.